# creating a has_many through relationship and testing it with rspec

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

Im pretty new to rails. Im trying to create a simple has_many through relationship between two tables performer and performance. 
I cant even get the basic rspec test to pass. I have no idea what im doing wrong

here is the error i get

```
  1) Performers to Performances relationship
     Failure/Error: let(:relationship) { performer.performer_performances.build(
performance_id: performance.id) }
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Performer::PerformerPerformance
     # ./spec/models/performer_performance_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <t
op (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/performer_performance_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <t
op (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/performer_performance_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <t
op (required)>'
```

and here is my rspec file (i switched the approach to the cleaner more minimalistic test for now but you can see what i want to pass but i commented it out)

---

.\spec\models\performer_performance_spec.rb

---

```
    require 'spec_helper'

describe "Performers to Performances relationship" do


   let(:performer) { FactoryGirl.create(:performer) }
   let(:performance) { FactoryGirl.create(:performance) }
   let(:relationship) { performer.performer_performances.build(performance_id: performance.id) }

   subject { relationship }
   it { should be_valid }
    #before do 
    #  @example_performer   = FactoryGirl.create(:performer)
    #  @example_performance = FactoryGirl.create(:performance)
    #end

    it "should recognise when a performer has no performances" do
     # @example_performer.performances.count.should == 0
    end
    it "should handle a performer with a performance" do
     # @example_performer.performances << @example_performance
     # @example_performer.performances.count.should == 1
    end

   it "should automatically know a performance's performer" do
     # @example_performer.performances << @example_performance
     # @example_performance.performers.count.should == 1
   end
   it "should not allow the same artist twice in a performance" do
      # @example_performance.performers << @example_performer
      # @example_performance.performers << @example_performer
      # @example_performance.performers.count.should == 1
   end
end
```

here are my files

---

.\app\models\performance.rb

---

```
   class Performance < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :file_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 },  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
   validates :date, length: { maximum: 30 }  
   validates :location, length: { maximum: 50 }
   has_many :performer_performances, dependent: :destroy  
   has_many :performers, through: :performer_performances
end
```

---

.\app\models\performer.rb

---

```
class Performer < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 },  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
   has_many :performer_performances, dependent: :destroy  
   has_many :preformances, through: :performer_performances
end
```

---

.\db\migrate\20140315155732_create_performer_performance.rb

---

```
class CreatePerformerPerformance < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :performer_performances do |t|
      t.belongs_to :performer
      t.belongs_to :performance
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
    add_index :performer_performances, :performer_id
    add_index :performer_performances, :performance_id
    add_index :performer_performances, [:performer_id, :performance_id], unique: true
end
```

---

.\spec\factories.rb

---

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  sequence :name do |n|
    "slimshady#{n}"
  end

  factory :performer do
       name :name    
  end
  factory :performance do
    file_name     :name
    date          Date.new(2008, 12, 22)
    location      "lame house" 
  end

end
```

i run the `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and `test:prepare`

just in case my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'  #ch9.29

gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4' #ch9.3 
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'

group :development :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

I failed to find any typos so im updating this. 
Im running windows vista x64 if that changes anything...

Comment: have you modified spec_helper? Are you sure that Rspec is working correctly?

Comment: yes i did modify spec helper but i removed my modifications now and i still get the same errors. I added `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
config.use_instantiated_fixtures  = false` to it before. Other than that i only added `config.include Capybara::DSL` but that was really long ago. Also im pretty sure rspec is working correctly cuz my basic tests for performer and performance are passing just fine (using the let(:){} syntax)

Comment: What does your spec_helper require?

Comment: `require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'` all autogenerated

Comment: Ok there is no error that I can see, but this kind of error can be the result of a misspelled file or an unexpected location for the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't show the file, I assume you haven't created a `performer_performance.rb` file in `app/models`.  The migration takes care of creating the database table, but you still need to create the ActiveRecord model by create the subject file with the appropriate class definition.

The error you're getting is because Ruby/Rails is encountering the constant reference (i.e. `PerformerPerformance`) and can't find a corresponding file with a corresponding definition.

Comment: you are right the file was missing. It normally auto-generates the model files I didnt manually create performer.rb or peformance.rb. I just assumed since it is an empty file and it wasn't generated that i didn't need it. Thank you I spend way too long trying to figure this out and probably would never find it without your help.